# Exchange default key binding for run commands in jupyterlab

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I wish to exchange the keybindings between "run the cell and move to the next" and "run the cell without jumping to the next" in jupyterlab. The default keybindings for these commands are `Shift Enter` and `Cntrl Enter` respectively when using the editing mode.

As a first step I tried to disable the current keybinding for `Shift Enter` by passing the argument `"disabled": true`. Unfortunately none of the combinations seems to get me what I want. The below is a code I tried the last in the user preferences -> keyboard shortcuts.

```
{
    "shortcuts":[
    {
       "command": "notebook:run-cell-and-select-next",
            "keys": [
                "Shift Enter"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus",
        "disabled": true
}
]
}
```

The command `notebook:run-cell-and-select-next` was found in the documents here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5371

I am not sure about the "command" and "selector" combinations for both these requirements and I did not find any sources till now where they are described more specifically. Any help would be appreciated.